# I have some doubts when using the busybox image

Tags: image, docker, busybox

I use `sudo docker pull busybox:latest` to download busybox image. And it's 1.2MB.

I use `sudo docker inspect busybox:latest` to find data directory. It's `/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0ca30bdc9f5eacfcc7838b165fd811d39c883b4859b256765b55c2e0b3b1710f`.

Using `du -sh /var/lib/docker/overlay2/0ca30bdc9f5eacfcc7838b165fd811d39c883b4859b256765b55c2e0b3b1710f`, shows 1.3MB. But when I come into  `/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0ca30bdc9f5eacfcc7838b165fd811d39c883b4859b256765b55c2e0b3b1710f/diff/bin`, I find that there are many executable files. Each of them occupies 1.1MB. Total 432MB.

Why does `du -sh` not count the size of these files?

When I `cp` `/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0ca30bdc9f5eacfcc7838b165fd811d39c883b4859b256765b55c2e0b3b1710f` to other directory. `du -sh` in the new directory does count these files. I am very confused.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're all the same file, so **du**(1) doesn't multiple-count them.  (This is required by [the POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/du.html).)   You'll see this if you run `ls -i` on the directory: every command there will have the same number, where that number uniquely identifies the actual underlying file on disk.

The way Busybox works, there's a single binary that provides all of the built-in commands, and when it starts up it looks at the name it was started as to decide what to do.  The **ln**(1) command will by default create a hard link or alternate name for an existing file:

```sh
# copy a to b1; if you delete a then b1 is still intact
cp a b1
# b has the name of a; if you delete a then b2 is "dangling"
ln -s a b2
# b3 is a; if you delete a then b3 is fine; if you change a you change b3 too
ln a b

ls -li
```

So `sh`, `cp`, `busybox`, *etc.* are literally all the same (compact) file, and that's why a Docker image (or bootable medium) based on Busybox is so tiny.

Comment: Oh, I got it! Thank you!